# Overriding application.property from env.properties as null

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have a DB connection using separated properties.

1. serverName=MyServerName
2. databaseName=MyDbName
3. instance=MyInstance

I want to override these with env.properties and this is working however the 'instance' property needs to be left blank. I've tried passing in the env.properties with a blank entry for 'instance' however it does not override the default 'MyInstance' (others are overridden fine).

Is this possible? If so, please may you give an example?

Comment: Where are you using those properties? some `application.properties`, `environment variables`, some resource?

Comment: I am using them within a Spring \@Configuration class via @Value annotations. They are used to create a DB connection via JtdsDataSource object.

Comment: `instance` is a very generic word, use `instanceName`